# How to show one of the many divs with the same id using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use JQuery to show/hide one of the many divs with the same id on hover of one of the links that have a shared id.

Markup Snippet

```
<div id='menuOption'>
<a href='#'><div id='cat_name'>$sub[cat_title]</div></a>
<div id='sub_menu' style='display:none;'>$itemlist</div></div>";
```

Query Snippet (What I tried):

```
$("#cat_name", this).hover(function(){
      $("#sub_menu", this).show();
});
$("#cat_name", this).mouseleave(function(){
      $("#sub_menu", this).hide();
});
```

I appreciate any info that might help me figure this out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML ids need to be unique. Select the html elements using classes instead.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GPhsC/2/

HTML

```
<div class='menuOption'>
    <a href='#'><div class='cat_name'>$sub[cat_title]</div></a> 
    <div class='sub_menu' style='display:none;'>$itemlist</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".cat_name").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub_menu").show();
},
function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub_menu").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Having multiple elements with the same ID attributes is incorrect markup.

You should identify groups of elements by their class attribute.

For your example

```
<div class='menuOption'> <a href='#'><div class='cat_name'>$sub[cat_title]</div></a> 
<div class='sub_menu' style='display:none;'>$itemlist</div></div>";
```

and

```
$(".cat_name", this).hover(function(){
       $(".sub_menu", this).show();
});
$(".cat_name", this).mouseleave(function(){
      $(".sub_menu", this).hide(); 
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response... well, I tried using classes for my elements instead of id's and that still does not work...

Comment: @MatanelMattHazan you might want to provide a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) example with your question so we can see everything in the correct context.